# How to use URL pattern in filterRegistrationBean

Tags: spring-boot, url, filter, pattern-matching

I am unable to generalize my desired URL patterns in the filter registration as my URLs are

- `http://localhost:8080/service/v1/dsply`,
- `http://localhost:8080/service/v1/smry/smry1`,
- `http://localhost:8080/service/v1/smry/smry2`

Where my root context is `service/v1`. I want to include every thing after `v1`.
Is it possible to include root context in addUrlPatterns .

I have already tried patterns like `/v1/**`, `/v1/*`, `/v1/*/` but none seems to work. But if I use the endpoints like `/dsply`, `/smry/*` it is working.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean fltrRgst(){
    FilterRegistrationBean rgst = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    rgst.setFilter(new myFilter());
    rgst.setOrder(1);
    rgst.addUrlPatterns("/v1/*","/v1/*/")
}
```

Comment: What is your root context?

Comment: try setting `**/v1/**`